# Query from a Table, That's derived from a Information_Schema.Tables Result

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, information-schema

I'm having to query from a Database that has more than 50 tables - all having the same structure (I know, Horrid Database design from a legacy project that's been in production for 5+ years!). To do this, I've queried the `information_Schema` like below:

```
    SELECT 
        TABLE_NAME 
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =
        'projectdatabase'   
            AND 
        TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_usertable'
```

Which provides me the 50 or so tables that I need, in a result. Now, I will need to query columns from within each of those tables for example, `PRODUCT_ID`. In doing so, I've attempted:

```
    SELECT 
        projectdatabase.userTable.PRODUCT_ID
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            TABLE_NAME as userTable 
        FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =
            'projectdatabase'   
                AND 
            TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_usertable'
    ) AS userTables
```

Now this obviously doesn't work due to MySQL not treating the 'userTable' as Database table - but what I'm attempting to do, is query `* FROM {tablename}` where `tablename` was the `information_schema` query result.

I could attempt to split this up in PHP, although I'm eagerly wondering if this was possible to do within MySQL.

Comment: Interesting question trying to deal with a messed up database schema. As a professional turd polisher, I'm looking forward to seeing what folks have to say about this. I have no idea, I'd do it in PHP, but it seems like you should be able to it in MySQL.

Comment: @gnarly I fear it's not possible yet (Understandably so), I'm hoping a bounty will change that..!

Comment: Assuming that the schema is stable and there are no new tables `%_usertable` added to the database, I would create a view that `union all` these 50 tables. To build the definition text of the view I would use your query of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables`, but it will be a one-off exercise.

Comment: In fact, if the schema is stable, there is another, possibly better way (from the performance point of view). Create a new permanent table that contains all data from those 50 tables unioned together, plus an extra  column `type`, add an index on that column. Create 50 views that select from this single big table to return the data that originally was in the small tables. Give these views the same names as original small tables. If needed, create triggers on these views to intercept updates and redirect them to the big table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use prepared statement:

```
 SET @sql:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT("SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM ", TABLE_NAME) SEPARATOR " UNION ")
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'projectdatabase'   
            AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_usertable');
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

EDIT: You can also set `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`, but doing all in SQL is not a thing to do. Your table list is kind of a constant, and the query would be in a better place in your PHP code.

Comment: Looking like the most reliable answer; having said that - this didn't work due to `GROUP_CONCAT` length max but that's OK because it does just confirm that what I'm asking to do is just unfeasible!

Comment: yes you're right, I modify my answer to take this limitation in consideration

Answer (score 0):

Adam deserves the bounty. The `group_concat_max_len` can be captured and restored if you like.  And you can make it even larger.  So I don't see a reliability issue.  And I agree that you cannot have the tablename be a 'variable'.

The PHP equivalent would go something like:

1. Get the list of tables from

   ```
   SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'projectdatabase'   
               AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_usertable';
   ```
2. Either build the `UNION`, Adam's suggestion, or run the 50 `SELECT`'s, each based on one tablename from the above list.  Then combine them however you want.

Recommend thinking through `UNION DISTINCT` versus `UNION ALL`.